# Yii: can't modify the Yii->app()->session array after it was set

Tags: php, yii

I have set the followings:

```
Yii::app()->session['payment_detail'] = array(
                                'model_user_id' => $model->id,
                                'model_customer_id' => $model_customer->id,
                                'package_id' => $package_id,
                                'order_id' => $model['order']['item']['order_id'],
                                'order_created' => $model['order']['item']['created'],
                                'refresh' => 1);
```

now, i need to add data:

```
Yii::app()->session['payment_detail']['model_package'] = $model_package;
```

where `$model_package` is a `!empty array`;

when I use `print_r($model_package);` i see the array data;

Why when i use:

```
print_r(Yii::app()->session['payment_detail']['model_package']);
```

I get nothing?

Comment: Where do you store the session data? Can you make a switch to database session and see if this problem persists ?

Comment: there is something strange here; i can set the session array, but i cant modify it ?

Comment: You can modify it! Have you switched to db session? Also, please note that the session class has methods like `add`, try to use that as well. `Yii::app()->session->add('key', 'value')`. But i believe your problem is the fact that you don't save this data into database, it worth a try :)

Comment: like: Yii::app()->session['payment_detail']->add($key,$value); ?

Comment: No, not like that, you missed the point. See @soju reply, that's the right answer :) Oh, also, try to code with error reporting on, it will allow you to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, nothing strange, you cannot modify Yii session like this :

```
Yii::app()->session['payment_detail']['model_package'] = $model_package;
```

You should get the following error :

> **Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect**

You should simply try this :

```
$payment_detail = Yii::app()->session['payment_detail'];
$payment_detail['model_package'] = $model_package;
Yii::app()->session['payment_detail'] = $payment_detail;
```

PS: take a look here :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#get-detail

Comment: your code also overwrites my session array; i need to add data, not to reset the session array

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Did you start session? maybe it is not autostart;

> To start the session, call open(); To complete and send out session
>   data, call close(); To destroy the session, call destroy().
>
> If autoStart is set true, the session will be started automatically
>   when the application component is initialized by the application.
>
> CHttpSession can be used like an array to set and get session data.
>   For example,   $session=new CHttpSession;   $session->open();
>   $value1=$session['name1'];  // get session variable 'name1'
>   $value2=$session['name2'];  // get session variable 'name2'
>   foreach($session as $name=>$value) // traverse all session variables
>   $session['name3']=$value3;  // set session variable 'name3'

And about array session:
try this, not nice solution, but at least working one:

```
$session = Yii::app()->session;
$temp = $session['foo'];
$temp['bar'] = 3;
$session['foo'] = $temp;
```

Comment: I need a `session` not a `state`

Comment: Why cant I modify the session array ?

Comment: try again with newly added solution.

Answer (score 1):

try doing:

```
$session=new CHttpSession;
$session->open();
$session['payment_detail']['model_package'] = $model_package;
```

OR

```
$session = Yii::app()->session;
$temp = $session['payment_detail'];
$temp['model_package'] = $model_package;
$session['payment_detail'] = $temp;
```

Comment: The session will be opened when you first time access `Yii::app()->session`, you don't need to manually open it and you shouldn't manually open it.

Comment: you are overwriting the entire payment_detail array